# How can ı display all subsets that have 4 element of a set in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, subset, discrete-mathematics

A = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

Set of B is a subset of A . The set of B has **4** element and its smallest element is **4** in B. So, B = {{4,5,6,7},{4,5,6,8},......}

I can not create any algorithm or code in Java. How can ı display it? Thank you already.

Comment: `B` is not a subset of `A` in your example because `A` 's elements are *numbers* and `B`'s elements are *sets of numbers*.

Comment: SO is not a code machine! There is plenty of resource on this, have a look https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-subsets-given-size-set/